# customize a spinner to drop down a textview and reduce the size of two other spinners with the same customized dropdown

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, customization, android-spinner

So What My application does is query a Database, I finally have the query all worked out and I got it to display to a Textview. The problem is I want the user to be able to see the result of 3 separate but similar queries, all in the same Activity, in Textviews.

I have almost no knowledge of how to customize layout items in android and I really wanted to Have a layout with nothing but 3 spinners and whenever you click on one (or when you arrive at the Activity) to have one dropdown of a Spinner (Which has a textview) that takes up most of the screen but leaves enough room for the two other spinners to be clearly viewed and clicked but not displaying their textviews.

Then when one of the other Spinners are clicked, It would reduce the size of the spinner that was open (with textview) to just the spinner and open the dropdown (with textview) of the spinner that was just clicked.

I don't even know if this is possible and if it is where would I start?